# How to export data from a GUI executable using python

Tags: python, subprocess, screen-scraping, ui-automation, pywinauto

Here is a programm I want to get a token from(allocated with red):
[image]

I'm trying to do it using subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
sda = subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\SDA New\Steam Desktop Authenticator.exe', stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
outs = sda.communicate(timeout=15)[0]
print(outs)
```

it returns an emtry string. How can I get the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import clipboard

app = application.Application()
app.start(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\sda 1.06\Steam Desktop Authenticator.exe',
          timeout=5)
sda = app.window_(title_re="Steam Desktop Authenticator")
time.sleep(2)
sda.Copy.Click()
code = clipboard.GetData()
sda.Close()
```